# react native expo QRcode GENERATOR

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code

I want to build my app QRCODE GENERATOR in [React Native Expo](https://expo.io/).

I work with QR code - module [react-native-qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode) version 0.2.7, and I have this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRAXM.jpg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react-native-qrcode` is no longer maintained.

You can use `react-native-qrcode-svg` package

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-svg

```
yarn add react-native-qrcode-svg
```

OR

```
npm install --save react-native-qrcode-svg
```

Comment: its also not maintained any longer

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text,} from 'react-native';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode';
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  inputValue: '',

  valueForQRCode: '',

    };
}

  getTextInputValue = () => {
this.setState({ valueForQRCode: this.state.inputValue });
};

 render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

    <TextInput
      style={styles.TextInputStyle}
      onChangeText={text => this.setState({ inputValue: text })}
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      placeholder="Enter text to Generate QR Code"
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this.getTextInputValue}
      activeOpacity={0.7}
      style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> Generate QR Code </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
}
}
     export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library that I open sourced: [react-native-barcode-creator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-barcode-creator), it generates natively QR Code, Code128, AZTEC and PDF417 barcode, works for both iOS and Android